# formで入力した内容をreq.getParameter("");で受け取ろうとしてもnullになってしまう

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

JSPファイルのformで入力した内容がservletで受け取ろうとしても中身がnullになってしまう原因がわからないので教えていただきたいです。
中身がnullかどうかはデバッグをしていて確認したのですが、原因がわかりませんでした。
Bootstarp4を使っているのですが、formでの送信の方法が違っていたりするのでしょうか？
別サイトで質問したのですが、なかなか回答が付きません。
よろしくお願いします。

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<title>ジョイステ</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/blog-post.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- fontawesome-->
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- テキストエディタ「Quilljs」のライブラリ -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Quillカスタマイズjs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\quillcustom.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="background-color: #f5f5f5; padding-top: 7%;">

    <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top"
        style="background-color: #55c500;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"
                alt="" class="img-fluid h-25 w-25"><img
                src="images/joystekun.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"
                style="width: 10%; height: 10%;"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link display-5"
                        href="loginhome.jsp">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link display-5"
                        href="mypage.jsp">MyPage <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item disabled"><a class="nav-link display-5"
                        href="post.jsp">Post <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container pb-5">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Post Content Column -->
            <div class="col-lg-8 pb-5">

                <!-- Title -->
                <h1 class="mt-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>投稿画面
                </h1>

                <!-- Post Content -->
                <form action="PreviewServlet" method="POST"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>タイトル</label> <input class="form-control" placeholder="タイトル"
                            type="text" name="title" size="50">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Category -->
                    <p>カテゴリー</p>
                    <div class="d-inline-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">&#9758;</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="category1" class="form-control"
                                        aria-label="Sizing example input"
                                        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" list="category"
                                        placeholder="カテゴリーを選択">
                                    <datalist id="category">
                                        <option value="体づくり"></option>
                                        <option value="料理"></option>
                                        <option value="DIY"></option>
                                        <option value="ゲーム"></option>
                                        <option value="音楽"></option>
                                        <option value="読書"></option>
                                    </datalist>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">&#9758;</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="category2" class="form-control"
                                        aria-label="Sizing example input"
                                        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" list="category"
                                        placeholder="カテゴリーを選択">
                                    <datalist id="category">
                                        <option value="体づくり"></option>
                                        <option value="料理"></option>
                                        <option value="DIY"></option>
                                        <option value="ゲーム"></option>
                                        <option value="音楽"></option>
                                        <option value="読書"></option>
                                    </datalist>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">&#9758;</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="category3" class="form-control"
                                        aria-label="Sizing example input"
                                        aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" list="category"
                                        placeholder="カテゴリーを選択">
                                    <datalist id="category">
                                        <option value="体づくり"></option>
                                        <option value="料理"></option>
                                        <option value="DIY"></option>
                                        <option value="ゲーム"></option>
                                        <option value="音楽"></option>
                                        <option value="読書"></option>
                                    </datalist>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <!-- img -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">イメージ</label> <input
                            type="text" name="image" class="form-control-file"
                            id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                    </div>

                    <!-- editor-body -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>投稿内容</label>
                        <textarea name="content" class="form-control"
                            id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="30"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <!-- editor-footer -->
                    <div class="button">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary editorSubmit_submitBtn"
                            tabindex="12" type="submit" style="background-color: #adff2f;">
                            <span class="editorSubmit_submitBtnLabel active"> <i
                                class="fa fa-upload"> </i>プレビュー
                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>

            <!-- Sidebar Widgets Column -->
            <div class="col-md-4">


                <!-- Search Widget -->
                <div class="card my-4">
                    <h5 class="card-header">検索</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="記事タイトルを入力">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- User menu Widget -->
                <div class="card my-4">
                    <h5 class="card-header">ユーザーメニュー</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>
                            <i class="far fa-edit"></i><a href="post.jsp">日記投稿</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i><a href="userChange.jsp">ユーザー情報変更</a>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i><a href="home.jsp">ログアウト</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- User info Widget -->
                <div class="card my-4">
                    <h5 class="card-header">ユーザー情報</h5>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-md-6">
                                <h3 class="mb-0 text-truncated">ID:12345</h3>
                                <h3 class="mb-0 text-truncated">JAVA山JAVA郎</h3>

                                <p class="mb-0 text-truncated">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>メールアドレス
                                </p>
                                <p>私はカレーが好きです。</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="badge badge-info tags">筋トレ</span> <span
                                        class="badge badge-info tags">ヨガ</span> <span
                                        class="badge badge-info tags">DIY</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6 text-center">
                                <img
                                    src="C:\Users\Owner\Documents\aグループ開発TNT\モックアップ構成\images\tag2.jpg"
                                    alt="" class="mx-auto rounded-circle img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> 日記
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">
                                    <span class="fa fa-user"></span>タグ
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">
                                    <span class="fa fa-search"></span> 検索
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!--/col-->
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Your
                Website 2019</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>
    <script
        src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>

    <script>
        // 通常のエディタ
        var quill_1 = QuillEditorMake("quill-editor_1")
        // 通常のエディタ（文章あり）
        var quill_2 = QuillUpdateEditorMake("quill-editor_2",
                quill_1.getContent)
        // 編集不可エディタ（記事表示用）
        var quill_3 = QuillPageMake("quill-editor_1", quill_1.getContent)
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```java
package controller.post;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/PreviewServlet")
public class PreviewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String title = req.getParameter("title");
        String content = req.getParameter("content");
        String image = req.getParameter("image");
        String category1 = req.getParameter("category1");
        String category2 = req.getParameter("category2");
        String category3 = req.getParameter("category3");

        Date dateNow = new Date();

        String date = String.valueOf(dateNow);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add(title);
        list.add(content);
        list.add(image);
        list.add(category1);
        list.add(category2);
        list.add(category3);
        list.add(date);

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        session.setAttribute("DATALIST", list);

        String move = "postresult.jsp";

        req.getRequestDispatcher(move).forward(req, resp);

    }
}
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/271716

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事解決いたしました！

Comment: 失礼いたしました。user20098さんが回答されてくださいました。<form>のenctypeの指定を削除することで解決することができました。

Answer (score 1):

HTMLソースを見る限り、ファイルアップロードはしていないようなので、`<form>`の`enctype`の指定を削除すればよいと思います。(`enctype`はデフォルトの`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`でよいと思います)

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事解決いたしました！